# Position JavaFX Button in a specific location

Tags: button, layout, javafx, position, location

My Question is how can i position a javafx button in a specific location.

All the time that i tried to do this simple code is resulting that the Button is only located in the Center of the screen and not on my desired location.

(I'm using StackPane)

Code:

```
Button button = new Button();

button.setLayoutX(x);
button.setLayoutY(y);
```

Thanks in advance ,

Amit.

Comment: Which layout are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying , I'm using StackPane

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to specify the exact co-ordinates of your node, you can use a [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead of *StackPane*.

---

Your button, if added to a `StackPane` or similar layout which supports alignment, must use the translate properties to move the button. You cannot use `setLayoutX()` or `setLayoutY()` with these layouts.

Try using the following command to move the button from its initial location :

```
button.setTranslateX(10);
button.setTranslateY(20);
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is still not working and yes I'm using StackPane and Thanks for replying

Comment: Translate will move the node from its current location by the specified value and not place it on the exact X, Y co-ordinate.

Comment: So what do i need to do to make it on the exact X and Y of my desired co-oridnate?

Comment: Use a Pane instead of a StackPane

Comment: Use a Pane, as stated by @James_D